# Can you initialize a dynamically-sized variable-length array to zero?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c11, zero-initialization

In the book [21st Century C Tips From the New School](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033677.do). On page 171 it says,

> Now for the sad part: let us say that you have a variable-length array (i.e., one whose length is set by a runtime variable). The only way to zero it out is via `memset` :
>
> ```
> int main(){
>   int length=20;
>   int ll[length];
>   memset(ll, 0, 20*sizeof(int));
> }
> ```
>
> So it goes. 1.

The footnote for that section reads,

> 1. You can blame ISO C standard §6.7.8(3) for this, because it insists that variable length arrays can’t be initialized. I say the compiler should be able to work it out.

I don't see this mentioned anywhere though in the [seminal answers on this matter on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value) which seem to suggest that this would work,

```
int main(){
  int length=20;
  int ll[length] = {0};
}
```

Is this the proper reading of the ISO C 2011 Standard?

Comment: `I don't see this mentioned anywhere though in the seminal answers on this matter on StackOverflow` Probably because the linked question doesn't mention variable length arrays at all.

Comment: You cannot initialize VLA's, instead use `memset` or a loop.

Comment: Or better don't use VLA... => I'm already gone

Comment: ... (or calloc)

Comment: What amazes me is the hardocded `20*sizeof(int)`, instead of `sizeof ll`. I mean, if the book professes to teach C, it shouldn't have brittle code in it.

Comment: Worse yet is the use of identifiers such as `ll` or `l`. This is a _very_ old and well-known no-no discovered somewhere in the 1970s-1980s. I'd expect a moderately experienced C programmer to be aware of it - let alone someone bold enough to write a C book. 21st century, right...

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, `sizeof ll` is potentially less efficient than `20*sizeof(int)`. Because: VLA.

Comment: @Lundin link or docs that explain your statement?

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I would expect that if `ll` is a VLA, using `sizeof` on it would result in a compiler computing its size at run time.  A compiler might recognize some cases where the length would always be the same, but I'm not sure the value of such optimizations would be worth the effort.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's because of the familiarity in the font between `1` (one) and `l` (L). Using `l` as variable name is banned by MISRA-C, [CERT-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152241) etc.